# Find a way to list all users in business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

We have a landing page that lists all users in each business unit in our Enterprise 2.0 account. The page is populated by using AccountUserAccount object in SOAP API.

Unfortunately, we have just heard that AccountUserAccount is going to be deprecated in June and we are looking for another solution.

Does anyone know how to get all associated users in a business unit?
Any opinion would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you hear about SOAP API objects being deprecated?

Comment: We ask the Marketing Cloud support for the usage of AccountUserAccount but instead they reply us it is going to be deprecate it without providing another solution.

Comment: Honestly surprised that SFMC support said anything about the API.

Comment: That would be nice if they can add an user list in the Account object's retrieve function before they decide to deprecate AccountUserAccount. I really hope more people can ask them to do.